# Does MySQL Faithfully perform a Search if Criteria Obviously Matches all Cases in a Column

Tags: mysql, performance

I was wondering whether I need to put up a conditional statement to remove a criteria if that criteria is such that it covers all possible values in the column. Example as follows:

```
SELECT product FROM Table where condition = 'condition' AND class <= 255;
```

Let's say the class column is of `TINYINT unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`. Will MySQL still faithfully scan through the column to check if `class <= 255`? How does the above query performs vis-a-vis this statement below assuming I have 10 million rows?

```
SELECT product FROM Table where condition = 'condition';
```

---

After some testing on my own database, I realise that MySQL **does faithfully scan** through the entire column although it is obvious that the search would return the whole column. The difference in performance for my case is in the order of **a few seconds**. There is no difference between the two query plans.

I would like to further add that a scan will also be performed for query below:

```
SELECT product FROM Table where condition = 'condition' AND class >= 0;
```

I am not sure why such query is not optimised by MySQL. I hope someone can enlighten me with an answer. Thank you :)

Comment: `tinyint(1)` is the same as `tinyint` and can store values between -128 and 127: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: In the MySQL console, run `EXPLAIN SELECT product FROM Table where condition = 'condition' AND class <= 9;` and `EXPLAIN SELECT product FROM Table where condition = 'condition';` and see if you get a different execution plan.

Comment: @ michael, I see you are right about this. Let me revise my question to make it more applicable.

Comment: @ Asaph, the query plan is exactly the same.

Comment: The column would have to be `NOT NULL` for `class <= 255` to be guaranteed to match all rows. BTW I have tested in SQL Server and this too doesn't detect this unless an apparently redundant check constraint is added to the column. `CREATE TABLE #T(X TINYINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,Y TINYINT  NOT NULL CHECK (Y BETWEEN 0 AND 255),Z INT UNIQUE);SELECT Z FROM #T WHERE Y <= 255`

Comment: @ Martin: yes, the column is indeed NOT NULL, I will put that in as well.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Is there an index on `condition` that would allow it to solve the `condition = 'condition'` part directly? If so, it should do that. If not, then it is going to need to scan the whole table anyway, since all rows would have `class <= 255`.

Comment: @ Avi, this is an apple to apple comparison. For my case, I have a partial index on `condition`. If MySQL needs to scan one additional column, wouldn't there be a time difference even if there is no index on `condition`?

Comment: Not necessarily. The major bottleneck in select performance usually tends to be the number of records scanned, not the number of fields checked per record. Of course, these are subtle differences, and in some cases it may make a difference, depending on your data and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not eliminate non-sensical criteria, such as `class >= 0` on a unsigned integer column.

Here's a list of all `where` optimizations that MySQL does:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html

MySQL does however detect that `class >= 0` will have many hits and will not try and use an index.
As far as the `condition = 'condition'` clause goes, whether it uses an index is determined by the cardinality of that column.
Of more than say 20% of the rows meet the condition a full table scan will be performed, if not an index will be used.

If both criteria can use an index, the index with the highest expected cardinality will be used.
MySQL will only ever use one index per table per subselect/join.

MySQL does not eliminate where criteria from evaluation but it does perform short circuit boolean evaluation on AND and OR.
So it **will** avoid a full table scan **if** it can use an index on `condition`.

**If MySQL does a full table scan**
It will have to do the other test on `class` only for those rows that match `condition`, but not for all rows.
The query-optimizer will evaluate the clauses in the order that yield the fastest results, so it should evaluate `condition` first (because it's a `=` comparison) and then `class` (because its a > test with a low value).

Comment: as discussed with Avi, whether there is an index or not on `condition`, MySQL still performs a check on the `class` column. With index, this process is expedited. This part of the question has been answered. The second part as to why such optimisation wasn't done, is not.